# How to Make AJAX file uploader for IE7/8 without jQuery or iframes or flash?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I searched on the web and I found a lot of solutions with jQuery & iframes.

Can anyone give me solution How to Make AJAX file uploader for IE7/8 without jQuery or iframes or flash?

This is my HTML script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <title>Ajax Uploader</title>
    <script>

    function iajax() 
    {
        oField=document.myform.myfile;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            { 
                document.getElementById('eds').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            } 
        };

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        xmlhttp.open("post","file.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='myform' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="iajax(this)">
        <input type="file" name="myfile" />
        <button type="submit">Upload file to the server</button>
    </form>
    <div id='eds'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php
$name=$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['myfile']['type'];
$size=$_FILES['myfile']['size'];
$temp_name=$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], './public/'.$name))
{
    echo "Image Uploading Error";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload Image Name : ".$name;
}
?>
```

Comment: Open _IE10_, navigate to a page with a file input (e.g. [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ywNBm/show/)), open console, switch to _IE7 Browser Mode_, select a file, type `console.dir(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0])`, look for anything relating to selected file other than the path, cry.

Comment: Thank you guys. I think I should use iframe!

Answer (score 1):

Not possible up till now with all the latest browsers I know, Files can't be send to the server without iframe if you want your browser not to be refreshed, even the well known js frameworks and plug-in uses the iframe. Not sure how the flash does that but the only possibilities are

1. Either don't use ajax
2. else use one of the above options you dont want to use